# Legendre Symbol $\left(\frac4p\right)$ is always congruent to $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

Let$\newcommand\leg[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}$ $\leg ap$ denote the Legendre symbol. 
In all cases $a=4$. and $p$ takes values of different odd prime numbers $p$.

- For $p=5$:
  $\leg 45$ -> $4^{(5-1)/2} \equiv1$
- For $p=7$:
  $\leg 47$ -> $4^{(7-1)/2} \equiv1$

We can keep going on and testing different primes in Legendre symbol as long as they keep being congruent to $1$.

but how can we say $\leg4p\equiv1$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: $\left({4\over p}\right)=\left({2\over p}\right)^2$ i.e. $4$ is always a square, because $4=2^2$.

Comment: ...and also for $p=3$.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the question now.

Answer (score 3):

The$\newcommand\leg[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}\newcommand\ifs{\text{if }}\newcommand\qr{\text{quadratic residue}}$ Legendre-symbol $\leg ap$ is defined as
$$\leg ap=\begin{cases}
1&\ifs a \text{ is a }\qr\bmod p\\
-1&\ifs a \text{ is not a }\qr\bmod p\\
0&\ifs p\mid a.
\end{cases}$$
[Euler's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) tells us that
$$\leg ap\equiv a^{(p-1)/2}\pmod p.$$

What you were doing is applying Euler's criterion. Because $4$ is a quadratic residue modulo every prime ($4$ is even a square) you're consistently getting $1$.

**Note:** the fact that $4$ is a square allows for an easier explanation why $4^{(p-1)/2}\equiv1\pmod p$ for every odd prime. We have
$$4^{(p-1)/2}=2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$
by Fermat's little theorem.
*(This is essentially how one direction of the equivalence in Euler's criterion is proved: if $a\equiv b^2$, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv b^{p-1}\equiv1$.)*